# Prove that $\kappa_F(A) \ge \sqrt{n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, condition-number, matrix-norms

> [image]

I reached at a point after solving it

$$\kappa_F(A) = \sqrt{\mbox{tr}(A^H A) \cdot \mbox{tr}(A^{-1}(A^{-1})^H}$$

Now I am stuck. How to proceed? Or, alternatively, a new approach is also appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint.* Every complex square matrix $X$ is unitarily triangulable and Frobenius norm is unitarily invariant. It follows that $\|X\|_F^2\ge\sum_i|\lambda_i(X)|^2$.

Comment: I tried this... And I guess for inverse it is reciprocal of these eigenvalues... .. but how to get n that's my main issue

Comment: @learningstudent E.g. $(a+b)(\frac1a+\frac1b)\ge2$ when $a,b>0$.

Comment: You are awesome..  thanks ..I got it nicely